# Why Xenomai Kernel doesn't support EFI handover?

Tags: ubuntu, xenomai

I have had an issue trying to run Xenomai Kernel.

I installed Ubuntu 20 in a VM from Hyper-V on Windows, inside this Ubuntu 20 I created and added a Xeonmai 4 kernel to this linux Kernel, now after add the group to the allowed groups in the grub file from etc/defaults/grub i'm trying to initilize this kernel but I got an error saying that Xenomai doesn't support EFI handover.

So my question would be, why Xenomai 4.19 doesn't support EFI handover? I'm not pretty sure of knowing what this means, Could I do something to make it support EFI handover? How can i change this EFI handover? or What is this EFI handover anyway? any answer or comment about it will be very helpfull

I attached a link to the image of the message I get when I select the Xenomai Kernel in the advanced options for ubuntu of the GRUB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udwwP.png)

Comment: Why doesn’t it support it? Because nobody had the time to write/debug the support in that particular kernel :)

Comment: That seems logic to me, but from where does this EFI comes? What I would have to do in order to run this Kernel in this VM?